# Entity Framework Core insert record into database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core in my project. My entity looks like this:

```
[Table("Policy")]
public class Policy
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }    
    public Bank Bank { get; set; }          
    public string LastUpdateBy { get; set; }    
}

[Table("Bank")]
public class Bank
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }    
    public string Code { get; set; }    
    public DateTime? CreateTs { get; set; } 
}
```

In SQL, this is how table `Policy` looks like:

```
Id (uniqueidentifier)
Bank (varchar)
LastUpdateBy (varchar)
```

I am referencing `Bank` in `Policy` entity because i would like to have a parent-child relationship.

When I am trying to add a record in `Policy` table, it's giving me following error

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Bank'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Bank'. The duplicate key value is (829e0798-c7ee-4fcf-b18d-0fbc60f63fad).

Here is my code:

```
var policy = new Policy
{
    Bank = new Bank
    {
        Id = "829e0798-c7ee-4fcf-b18d-0fbc60f63fad"
    },
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    LastUpdateBy = "User"
};

dbContext.Policy.Add(policy);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I know, it's trying to add a record in `Bank` table as well. How would I tell EF Core to insert record only in `Policy` table?

Comment: Hold a foreign key of the Bank's `GUID` inside of class `Policy`, not a `Bank` object

Comment: Any other way without changing entity?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, besides why would you not want to structure your entities correctly? A policy in no way should be creating a bank, that makes no sense.

Comment: The other ways would be to attach the bank instance to the dbcontext so it is tracked and marked as not changed. Then it won't be inserted on save changes. It would make more sense to include the fk in the child entity (Policy) and just set that instead of creating a new bank instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bank is an entity that exists as stated a (singleton), a bank will not change and it's properties are it's own. A policy is issued by a bank, therefore, a policy should reference a bank via the banks Guid or ID property (foreign key), this will then create the parent -> child relationship which you desire. This is a `ONE-TO-MANY` relationship. I think you may want to either spend some more time learning about database relational design or draw these things out on paper before creating your entity classes.

EDIT: Igor has given you an option to stay the course and not change your entities, but I think you should take a good hard look at structuring your entities in a way that would mirror a database relational design. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to introduce a foreign key for `Bank` then you have to attach bank first.

```
var bank = new Bank
{
    Id = "829e0798-c7ee-4fcf-b18d-0fbc60f63fad"
};
dbContext.Bank.Attach(bank);

var policy = new Policy
{
    Bank = bank,
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    LastUpdateBy = "User"
};

dbContext.Policy.Add(policy);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```